# i am a beginner in java !! my doublt is regarding = and new operator in case of objects

Tags: java, oop

to keep it simple i have only written 3 lines for code(not actually a code without corect syntax)

for a class A we are creating objects

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2;
a2 = a1;
```

what actually does = in a2 = a1 do??
until the previous line there was no memory allocated for a2 since we didnt use the new operator!! please point if i am wrong?

can we consider the reference of the object to be same as its address??(references = pointers)

can u correct me anyhow ?? i have googled it and am getting some mixed answers and unable to understand what exactly they try to say!! 
they quote that we are unable to do arthmetic with references but can with pointers! but they both have the same basic concept -address
and so i thought they both meant the same thing

next we are passing reference of a1 to a2 using = operator 
where is this reference (address) stored when no memory is being allocated for a2 ?

if memory is being allocated how is it being done??

Comment: Why do you care about memory allocation? What is your question?

Comment: There is plenty of information available regarding the java memory model, on this site and elsewhere. Please read that and show some research effort before asking fundamental questions.

Comment: Only `new` allocates memory on the heap, a new object. Variables hold a kind of pointer (4 bytes) referencing that heap object. hence a1 and a2 share the single object.

Comment: @LutzHorn horn how is the referencing being done 
i mean in c++ we create a pointer variable to store an address so basically we have a memory slot to store address
where as here without any memory being allocated how is the referencing being done actually!!

Comment: @selfish memory is always allocated whenever you declare a variable (read references) or create and object using `new` keyword.

Comment: but isnt it different in case of object - that we require to use new keyword before getting memory allocated for the object

Comment: Yes, that's how Java was designed to work.

Comment: Check this out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

Answer (score 1):

Pointers and reference are not same. There is difference between the two.
= and new are not same either.
new allocates memory for an object. = does not.

Reference can be stored in a JVM allocated table and it does not require memory allocation for itself. while new Object() is stored in memory heap of JVM.

Reference and pointers(in C language) are similar in a way that these refer to objects. But it does not mean that these are same thing. JVM encapsulates implementation details that means it hides implementation details from the programmer. Programmer does not have to know, how the object is being stored. He does not have pointers to data. Instead he has reference to call an object's methods and data.

Comment: can you please tell me under what topic does this come under java!!
i would like to go through this in deapth!! so that it will be clear.

thanks in advance

Comment: 1) This might help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html. 2) Read some java book for beginner.